# How to parse the xml with xmlns attribute using python

Tags: python, xpath, elementtree

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<school xmlns="loyo:22:2.2">
    <profile>
        <student xmlns="loyo:5:542">
            <marks>
                <mark java="java:/lo">
                    <ca1>200</ca1>
                </mark>
            </marks>
        </student>
    </profile>
</school>
```

I trying to access the **ca1** text. I am using etree but I cannot access it. I'm using below code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('mca.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def getElementsData(xpath):
    elements = list()
    if root.findall(xpath):
        for elem in root.findall(xpath):
            elements.append(elem.text)
        return elements
    else:
        raise SystemExit("Invalid xpath provided")



t = getElementsData('.//ca1')
for i in t:
    print(i)
```

I tried in different way to access it I don't know the exact problem. Is it recording file type issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document has namespaces on nodes **school** and **student**, you need to incorporate the namespaces in your search. Since you are looking for **ca1**, which is under **student**, you will need to specify the namespace that **student** node has:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('mca.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def getElementsData(xpath, namespaces):
    elements = root.findall(xpath, namespaces)
    if elements == []:
        raise SystemExit("Invalid xpath provided")
    return elements


namespaces = {'ns_school': 'loyo:22:2.2', 'ns_student': 'loyo:5:542'}
elements = getElementsData('.//ns_student:ca1', namespaces)

for element in elements:
    print(element)
```

Notes

- Since your namespaces have no names, I gave them such names as **ns_school**, **ns_student**, but these name can be anything (e.g. **ns1**, **mystudent**, ...)
- In a more complex system, I recommend raising some other kinds of errors and let the caller decide whether or not to exit.

Answer (score 0):

How about traversing like this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('test.xml').getroot()
data = e.getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].getchildren()[0].text
print(data)
```

Comment: I need xpath to access the element value @Apoorv Agarwal

Answer (score -1):

Try the following xpath

```
tree.xpath('//ca1//text()')[0].strip()
```